# DQL with between - string date - PHP

Tags: php, string, date, oracle11g, dql

I am trying to do a sql with between.
The date data is entered first as a string.
Any help with this question?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string is dd/mm/yyyy

```
$var = '28/09/2021';
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $var);
$fecha_inicio=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
//dd($fecha_inicio);
```

At the final you will get date like **2021-09-28** and now we can do a between with actual date **2021-10-01**

```
select t from App\Entity\table1 t, App\Entity\table2 s where s.id=t.id and s.id=50 AND (s.fecha_solicitud BETWEEN ('2021-09-28') AND ('2021-10-01') ) order by s.field1  asc, s.field2  asc, s.field3  asc
```

after this you can see the sentence in DB with **dd($query->getSQL());** function

```
SELECT 
  a0_.*, 
FROM 
  tabla1 a0_, 
  tabla2 s1_ 
WHERE 
  s1_.id = a0_.id 
  AND s1_.id = 23 
  AND (
    s1_.fecha_solicitud BETWEEN ('2021-09-28') 
    AND ('2021-10-01')
  )   
ORDER BY 
  s1_.field1 ASC, 
  s1_.field2 ASC, 
  s1_.field3 ASC
```